# addCircle to existing movieclip, using name of clip from an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently building a project where I have a map with a number of ship and aircraft. What I am trying to achieve is to check the Line of Sight distance between them.
I have set up a LOS Calculator which checks the height of one platform and the height of a second platform then gives a response. That works fine.

I then wanted to addCircle based on the result from this calculator. So if the result was 10 it would draw a circle 10cm in radius. If the result was 100 then it would draw it at 100, you get the picture. This works.

My problem now is that I need to be able to click on one platform either before or after I have made the calculation and the .addCircle be added to that movieClip. I have set up an array to store the movieclips instance names and traced that. I have added a field on stage so that you can click on a platform and it will recognise the platform clicked. I am just lost as to how to get the circle into the movieClip that has been clicked.

I am very new to AS3 so this is starting todo my head in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have is attached below. I hope I have inserted this properly. Thanks again

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stage.focus=ht1;


// creation of array containing movieclips and code that adds the clicked movieclip to Array-platformClicked
var platformArray:Array = [arunta_mc, f15_mc];
var platformClicked = [];
var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

for(var i:int = 0; i < platformArray.length; i++) {
    platformArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    platformArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, item_onClick);
}

function item_onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var selectedPlatformArray:Array = platformArray.filter(checkName);
    selectedPlatform = selectedPlatformArray[0];
    myText.text = event.currentTarget.name + " was clicked";
    var platformClicked = String(event.currentTarget.name);
trace(platformClicked);
}



function checkName(item:MovieClip, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
{
    return(item.name == platformClicked);
}



//setup of LOS Calculator code
var counter:Number=1;
operator_txt.text = "+";
ht1.restrict="-0123456789.";
ht2.restrict="-0123456789.";
var myresult:Number;
var test = [];

//start of code when equal button is pressed
equal_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, equalhandler);
var newCircle:Shape = new Shape();//defines circle to be drawn

    function equalhandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
        newCircle.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        newCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x435632);
        newCircle.alpha = .1;
    //start of result code
    result_txt.text = String(int((1.23*(Math.sqrt(Number(parseFloat(ht1.text)+parseFloat(ht2.text)+""))))));
    var test = String(int((1.23*(Math.sqrt(Number(parseFloat(ht1.text)+parseFloat(ht2.text)+""))))));
    trace(test);
    //end of result code
    newCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,test);//add circle based on LOS calculation
    newCircle.graphics.endFill();
    //var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = selectedPlatformArray[0];
    selectedPlatform.addChild(newCircle);//this is where I need to add newCircle to the movieClip that is clicked
    trace(selectedPlatform);
//trace(platformClicked);
}


//start of code for the clear button
clear_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearhandler);
function clearhandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
ht1.text=ht2.text=result_txt.text="";
removeChild(newCircle);
var test = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` method to check each item's name, like so:

```
var selectedPlatformArray:Array = platformArray.filter(checkName);
```

and somewhere in your code, define the `checkName` function

```
function checkName(item:MovieClip, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
{
    return (item.name == platformClicked);
}
```

`selectedPlatformArray` will now contain all elements that return `true` for the `checkName` function, and as long as you don't have multiple `MovieClips` with the same name the array should only contain one element, which you can retrieve simply by accessing the first element of the array:

```
var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = selectedPlatformArray[0];
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `getChildByName()` function, like so:

```
var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = stage.getChildByName(platformClicked);
```

However this depends on where the objects are added to, and if they're not all in the same container (or not added at all), then this isn't the best option. It's a quick and simple solution for small projects though.

Anyway, whatever method you use you can then easily add the circle to it in your `equalHandler` function as usual:

```
selectedPlatform.addChild(newCircle);
```

I'd recommend checking out the documentation for both [`filter()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29) and [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29), to get a better understanding of how they work, since my examples only showed how you'd use them in this specific situation.

---

Complete code that you should have:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stage.focus=ht1;


// creation of array containing movieclips and code that adds the clicked movieclip to Array-platformClicked
var platformArray:Array = [arunta_mc, f15_mc];
var platformClicked:String = "";
var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

for(var i:int = 0; i < platformArray.length; i++) {
    platformArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    platformArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, item_onClick);
}

function item_onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var selectedPlatformArray:Array = platformArray.filter(checkName);
    selectedPlatform = selectedPlatformArray[0];
    myText.text = event.currentTarget.name + " was clicked";
    platformClicked = String(event.currentTarget.name);
    trace(platformClicked);
}



function checkName(item:MovieClip, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
{
    return(item.name == platformClicked);
}



//setup of LOS Calculator code
var counter:Number=1;
operator_txt.text = "+";
ht1.restrict="-0123456789.";
ht2.restrict="-0123456789.";
var myresult:Number;
var test:String = "";

//start of code when equal button is pressed
equal_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, equalhandler);
var newCircle:Shape = new Shape();//defines circle to be drawn

function equalhandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    newCircle.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
    newCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x435632);
    newCircle.alpha = .1;
    //start of result code
    result_txt.text = String(int((1.23*(Math.sqrt(Number(parseFloat(ht1.text)+parseFloat(ht2.text)+""))))));
    test = String(int((1.23*(Math.sqrt(Number(parseFloat(ht1.text)+parseFloat(ht2.text)+""))))));
    trace(test);
    //end of result code
    newCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,test);//add circle based on LOS calculation
    newCircle.graphics.endFill();
    //var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = selectedPlatformArray[0];
    selectedPlatform.addChild(newCircle);//this is where I need to add newCircle to the movieClip that is clicked
    trace(selectedPlatform);
    //trace(platformClicked);
}


//start of code for the clear button
clear_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearhandler);
function clearhandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    ht1.text=ht2.text=result_txt.text="";
    selectedPlatform.removeChild(newCircle);
    test = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I have implemented your suggestion however I get the following error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at LOS_new_fla::MainTimeline/equalhandler()

Comment: Looks like a problem with the scope of `selectedPlatform`. Make sure to declare it outside of a function (next to `platformClicked` would do), then assign its value within `item_onClick`. If you do that it should work.

Comment: still get same problem. I will add my code again, and maybe the error of my ways will be noticeable.

Comment: just edited original question with the code after modification. I really appreciate the help you are giving.

Comment: OK, here's the problem: first of all, `selectedPlatform` should be a `MovieClip`, not an `Array`, so define it as `var selectedPlatform:MovieClip = new MovieClip();`. Secondly, move your `selectedPlatformArray` definition line inside the `item_onClick` function. Lastly, after that line, write `selectedPlatform = selectedPlatformArray[0];`, also within the `item_onClick` function. Try that. If that doesn't work (or my instructions aren't clear enough), I'll edit my answer with the complete code.

Comment: OK, made those changes. If I use the calculator first and then clip the platform they is no "null reference' error. However if I click the platform first then I get the "null reference" error. Either way though I dont get a circle round the platform. I apologise for the hassle. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well I saw a couple of mistakes in your code. First of all, you're not saying what data type `platformClicked` is, which is bad practice in AS3. You're also giving is a value of `[]`, which means an empty `Array`, even though you're using it as a `String`. Also, you're defining some variables like `platformClicked` and `test` more than once. That is, you only need to put `var` in front of a variable the first time that you create a variable. There are some other things, but anyway I've updated my post with the code that should work (although I haven't tested it).

Comment: puggsoy, you're a legend. I had to change "var test:String;" back to "var test=[];" as it was creating an error with the String on the end. Changed it back and it worked like a treat. I very much appreciate your time and you bearing with me. I ave a lot to learn and will now go and break this all down so I can completely understand. Thankyou so much

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help. Good luck with your project!